# Как сделать динамичный background, при заданном filter:blur?

Tags: html, css3, bootstrap

помогите решить проблему.
Есть header с содержимым, ему задал background-image, "заблюрил", задал linear-gradient, чтобы filter не вылез на весь блок header создал для этого отдельный блок .blur, туда же закинул весь фон, про который говорил выше, но проблема в том, что картинка в фоне не адаптивна по размерам. Нужно чтобы она подстраивалась под размер окна браузера. Буду благодарен за помощь.

```css
.top-nav {
 height: 100vh;
}

.blur { /*фильтр blur*/
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-size: cover;
 background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f8a261, #6e9fc9), linear-gradient(135deg, #08526b, #fbcd7c), 
 url(https://www.fillmurray.com/1140/698) no-repeat scroll;
 background-blend-mode: overlay, color;
 -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
}
```

```html
<section class="container-fluid top-nav"><!-- top-nav -->
  <div class="blur"></div>
</section>
```